# HTML Desktop Application, Read/Write File From HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, desktop-application

I have create an HTML application located on my computer, I use it with Firefox.

I need that this Html page reads and write on a simple txt file on my computer.

Preferably using only html/JS

Comment: Yes it is possible. But you only want to use a HTML file to download? Not using some help from TideSDK or AppJS?

Comment: I want use only html or javascript.
JS library are welcome.

Comment: @Bondye It's possible to Read/Write to a Text File from a HTML file using only JS? If you have some references or examples I'd like to know how, didn't think that was remotely possible.

Comment: @Nunners Yes, it's posible. Think about Node.js for example, a framework to create an API which access on a database saved into the hard disk. I don't know how but it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a definite solution

```
var txtFile = "c:/test.txt";
var file = new File(txtFile);
var str = "My string of text";

file.open("w"); // open file with write access
file.writeln("First line of text");
file.writeln("Second line of text " + str);
file.write(str);
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this documentation:

http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascriptexamples/javascript-write-to-text-file.shtml

That should help you get started.